# is there a way reverse proxy random subdomain

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

i'm trying to Reverse Proxy all requests to my server X1.site.com to another server lets say X1.site2.net, with X1 as a random subdomain name that chages everytime

i could't figure out how to do that using Nodejs so i'm using nginx

```
location /proxy {
    proxy_bind 127.0.0.1;
    proxy_pass http://site2.com/proxy/;
}
```

but it just doesn't work with dynamic subdomains

what i'm trying to achive is whatever the (X1,X2,X3).site.com subdomain are, just take it and add it to the target site to become (X1,X2,X3).site2.net so the code should look like

```
location X1.site.com {      //whatever the subdomain are take it and 
                            //pass it to proxy_pass 

    proxy_bind 127.0.0.1;
    proxy_pass X1.site2.net;       
}
```

Comment: If the `X1.site.com` is the domain name, it should appear in the `server_name` directive and not the `location` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith correct, is there a possible way to pass X1 to proxy_pass ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reverse proxy `something.example.com` to `something.example.net`, you would need to capture part of the domain name using a [*regular expression* `server_name` statement](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names).

For example:

```
server {
    server_name  "~^(?<name>.+)\.example\.com$";

    location / {
        resolver ...;
        proxy_pass http://$name.example.net;
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.